# I am Geting "TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable" when I dont call add anywhere?

Tags: python, addition

I have tried this code to get the root of the function y my code is

```
import sympy as sympy

W0 = 2000 #lbs/ft
L = 18 #ft
I = 0.03134645059 #ft^4
E = 29900 * 10**3 #psi

x = sympy.Symbol('x')

y = (W0/(120*E*I*L))*(-x**5 + 2*(L**2)*(x**3)-(L**4)*x)

y1 = sympy.diff(y)

print('For problem 3a, the first derivative is, \n', y1)

# set dy/dx = 0 solve using newton Rhapson

def NewtonRaphson(fun, fund, x_i, tol=1e-6, max_iter=10):
        
    counter = 0
    x_vals = [x_i]
    
    while abs(fun(x_i)) > tol and counter < max_iter:
       
        x_i -= (fun(x_i) / fund(x_i))
        x_vals.append(x_i)
        
        counter += 1
            
    return x_i

fun = y
fund = 0

x_i = 1000

Nroot = NewtonRaphson(fun, fund, x_i)

comp_root = scipy.optimize.fsolve(fun, fund, x_i)
print(comp_root)
```

and I always get the output "TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable" and I am not sure how to work around these errors.

Comment: Where is is `Add`? Could you share the trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mjlee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 160, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)

  File "C:\Users\mjlee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 226, in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))

  File "C:\Users\mjlee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 24, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))

TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable

Comment: I set y = a function of x

Comment: Please don't put this into the comment. Rather, [edit] your question. When properly formatted, it is much easier to read and understand then. In any case, it looks like there are multiple statements nested together. Unwrap them to find out which of them causes the error.